# Error "Can not get Python include directory. Is distutils installed?" when i build tensorflow on windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, build, failed-installation

I am currently trying to build the Tensorflow library on Windows 10. So I followed the instructions on this site: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/cmake/README.md

Here is what I wrote in the console:

```
C:\Users\Administrateur\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build>cmake .. -A x64 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ^
Plus ? -DSWIG_EXECUTABLE=C:\tools\swigwin-3.0.10\swig.exe ^
Plus ? -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\Users\Administrateur\AppData\Local\Anaconda\python.exe^
Plus ? -DPYTHON_LIBRARIES=C:\Users\Administrateur\AppData\Local\Anaconda\libs\python35.lib^
Plus ? -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=C:\Users\Administrateur\AppData\Local\Anaconda^
Plus ? -Dtensorflow_WIN_CPU_SIMD_OPTIONS=/arch:AVX^
Plus ? -Dtensorflow_WIN_CPU_SIMD_OPTIONS=/arch:SSE4.1^
Plus ? -Dtensorflow_WIN_CPU_SIMD_OPTIONS=/arch:SSE^
Plus ? -Dtensorflow_WIN_CPU_SIMD_OPTIONS=/arch:SSE4.2^
Plus ? -Dtensorflow_WIN_CPU_SIMD_OPTIONS=/arch:AVX2
```

And here is the error I encounter:

```
-- Found PythonInterp: C:/Users/Administrateur/AppData/Local/Anaconda/python.exe-DPYTHON_LIBRARIES=C:/Users/Administrateur/AppData/Local/Anaconda/libs/python35.lib-DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=C:/Users/Administrateur/AppData/Local/Anaconda-Dtensorflow_WIN_CPU_SIMD_OPTIONS=/arch:AVX-Dtensorflow_WIN_CPU_SIMD_OPTIONS=/arch:SSE4.1-Dtensorflow_WIN_CPU_SIMD_OPTIONS=/arch:SSE-Dtensorflow_WIN_CPU_SIMD_OPTIONS=/arch:SSE4.2-Dtensorflow_WIN_CPU_SIMD_OPTIONS=/arch:AVX2 (found version "1.4")
CMake Error at tf_python.cmake: 37 (message):
  Can not get Python include directory. Is distutils installed?
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt: 293 (include)


- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C: /Users/Administrateur/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/cmake/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C: /Users/Administrateur/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/cmake/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I do not understand: / I can see that *distutils* is installed, but then why does not it find ... Did you have a solution?

Comment: I would really like an answer to this question. I have successfully built TensorFlow r1.4, then successfully rebuilt it with options to use AVX/AVX2 instructions. I then used `git pull origin master` to update my tensorflow source to r1.6, and now I get this error.

Comment: Suggestion: check the "-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE" line closely. CMake uses this definition to define the python include path. In my case I simply had my path wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, but fixed it by using " "
so for instance:

DSWIG_EXECUTABLE="C:\tools\swigwin-3.0.10\swig.exe"